# sscanf - Scan certain part of string;

Tags: c, string-formatting

I have a formatted string and want to extract only certain parts of it. For example:

```
char * str = 618/3171 259/1429 557/2842;
```

Through sscanf I want three variables (integers) to hold the following variables:

```
i = 618
j = 259
k = 557
```

I can't seem to get the formatting right. Here is what I've tried:

```
sscanf(str, "%d %d %d", &i, &j, &k);
```

which returns:

```
i = 618
j = 0
k = 0
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code.

```
int main()
{
    const char *str = "618/3171 259/1429 557/2842";

    int i, j, k;
    sscanf(str, "%d/%*d %d/%*d %d/%*d", &i, &j, &k);

    printf("%d %d %d", i, j, k);
    return 0;
}
```

asterisk (`*`) skips value.
so don't need parameter for that.

Comment: You're a lifesaver. Thanks!